# WCF and HMACMD5 Authentication and Uri changed

Tags: wcf, rest

I am using HMACMD5 Authentication on a RESTFul wcf service. Part of the signature is based on the requested resource or the full url of the client's request.

I then attempt to validate the signature in the service. Since the requested URL is part of the signature I need to get that. I am trying to obtain the original url via:

```
WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.ToString();
WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.RequestUri.OriginalString;
```

This does not always work. I think this may be a domain issue because this is only at a testing stage on a testing server using SSL on the same domain.

For example, when I send across

_https://www.mytestingserver.com/GetResourcse/xxx/xxx

I am actually writing

_https://MYTESTSERVER-DMZ/xxx/xxx

to the logging in my service.

How can I test this, and more importantly, how can I ensure that I always can get what the client used in the signature after rewrites and what have you, because it is not in:

```
incomingRequestContext.UriTemplateMatch.RequestUri.OriginalString;
```

I have started to log almost everything with `WebOperationContext` and `OperationContext` to try to get this on the web server.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fyi

I can across this article:

[Allowing Access to HttpContext in WCF REST Services](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/Jan/10/Allowing-Access-to-HttpContext-in-WCF-REST-Services)

This works but perhaps there is a better way without altering the underlying protocol.